# How to Resize the Tensorflow Output Bounding Box to Original Image

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, tensorflow-lite

So, I am working on a Model, that I have successfully trained, it is a `.tflite` model and uses Tensorflow Lite. I am using Python 3 as my interface with tensorflow and I am unable to add a bounding box from the returned image.

My Question is:

## How to Resize the Tensorflow Output Bounding Box to Original Image

I am able to get the output for the `512x512` input file, but I am unable to go ahead and get a output for the original file, if I am correct. How to go ahead and re-size that output from my model in order to go ahead and crop that part from the original image and then save it.

[image: Image for AI]

## Code

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pathlib
import os
from silence_tensorflow import silence_tensorflow
from PIL import Image

silence_tensorflow()
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="model.tflite")

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

#print(input_details)
#print(output_details)

interpreter.allocate_tensors()

def draw_rect(image, box):
    h, w, c = image.shape
    y_min = int(max(1, (box[0] * h)))
    x_min = int(max(1, (box[1] * w)))
    y_max = int(min(h, (box[2] * h)))
    x_max = int(min(w, (box[3] * w)))

    # draw a rectangle on the image
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x_min, y_min), (x_max, y_max), (13, 13, 13), 2)

for file in pathlib.Path('./').iterdir():

    if file.suffix != '.jpeg' and file.suffix != '.png':
        continue

    img = cv2.imread(r"{}".format(file.resolve()))
    print(f'[Converting] {file.resolve()}')
    new_img = cv2.resize(img, (512, 512))

    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], [new_img])

    interpreter.invoke()
    rects = interpreter.get_tensor(
        output_details[0]['index'])

    scores = interpreter.get_tensor(
        output_details[2]['index'])

    for index, score in enumerate(scores[0]):
        if index == 0:
            print('[Quantity]')
            print(index,score)
        if index == 1:
            print('[Barcode]')
            print(index,score)
        if score > 0.2:
          draw_rect(new_img,rects[0][index])
          print(rects[0][index])

    cv2.imshow("image", new_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The Most easy solution for this problem is to go ahead and find the factor at which `h, w, c` of the downscaled image are compared to `h, w, c` of the original image.

That can be understood using the following piece of code.

```py
h, w, c = image.shape # old image 512x512
h1, w1, c1 = image2.shape # new image resize
h = (h1/h) * h
w = (w1/w) * w
c = (c1/c) * c
```

The new formed `h, w, c` values are belonging to the image2 or the **Original Image**.

## Draw Rectangle

In order to go ahead and draw a rectangle we are going to go ahead and use the following approach on this problem in order to go ahead and make it viable.

```py
def draw_rect(image,image2, box):
    h, w, c = image.shape # old image 512x512
    h1, w1, c1 = image2.shape # new image resize
    h = (h1/h) * h
    w = (w1/w) * w
    c = (c1/c) * c
    y_min = int(max(1, (box[0] * h)))
    x_min = int(max(1, (box[1] * w)))
    y_max = int(min(h, (box[2] * h)))
    x_max = int(min(w, (box[3] * w)))

    # draw a rectangle on the image
    cv2.rectangle(image2, (x_min, y_min), (x_max, y_max), (13, 13, 13), 2)
```